# XCText: query for text in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I've got a UITest that succeeds in iOS 10 (10.3):

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let pageTitle = app.navigationBars["Module.ContainerView"].staticTexts["page title"]
XCTAssert(pageTitle.exists)
```

This however fails in iOS 11 (11.1). The `app.navigationBars["Module.ContainerView"]` exists, the staticTexts of that is an empty array.

Any ideas how to test for a title in the navigation bar in iOS 11?

Comment: you can try to find the exact element by recording. Just start record and click on the navigation bar where the title is showing. It will provide you the exact element. I think the title element type changes.

     app.navigationBars[""Module.ContainerView"].otherElements[""page title"]   try with that

Comment: I was using a custom titleView in the navigation bar. In iOS 11, you need to set the `intrinsicContentSize` in order for the staticTexts to appear.

Comment: So you solved your problem by yourself? If So, Then post your solved answer here so that any one else facing similar issue get help.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the exact type of title by using the recording feature.

As a solution you can try with the below code.  Hope it will work.

```
 let app = XCUIApplication()
 let pageTitle = 
 app.navigationBars["Module.ContainerView"].otherElements["page title"]
 XCTAssert(pageTitle.exists)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let app = XCUIApplication()
    let navTitleIdentifier = "Community"
    let navigationTitleElement = app.navigationBars.matching(identifier: navTitleIdentifier).firstMatch
 XCTAssert(navigationTitleElement.exists)
```